# perl regex cisco configuration file print multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking for a perl regex that would match "vserver foo2" from the output below. However, I want to return the line of the match, and all the following lines up to the "!"   I only want to print the config for "vserver foo2"
Thx for the help!

Cisco config:
!
 vserver foo1
  description foo
  virtual 1.1.1.1 tcp www
  serverfarm foofoo
  persistent rebalance
  inservice
!
 vserver foo2
  description foo2
  virtual 1.1.1.2 tcp www
  serverfarm foofoo2
  persistent rebalance
  inservice
!
 vserver foo3
  description foo3
  virtual 1.1.1.3
  serverfarm foo3
  replicate csrp connection
  persistent rebalance
  inservice
!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
perl -ne 'print if /^vserver foo2/ .. /^!/' config.txt
```

Comment: thats why i love perl. it just gets what you mean :)

Answer (score 1):

```
open IN, '<', '1.txt';
while(<IN>) {
    if (/^vserver foo2$/) { $found = 1 }
    last if (/^!$/ and $found);
    print if $found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $content has all the file, then you should do something like:

```
my ($config) = $content =~ m/\n!\n(vserver foo2[^!]*)/sm;
```

assuming that you don't have a the '!' somewhere in your configuration.

But a better way to do it, I think, will be to run a loop, and skip the regex:
assuming the $fh is the file handle:

```
my $line;
# cut the leading lines
do {
  $line = <$fh>;
  chomp $line;
while ($line ne "!");

while ($line = <$fh>) {
   chomp $line;
   my $found = ($line eq "vserver foo2");
   while ($line = <$fh>) {
      chomp $line;
      break if $line eq "!";
      say $line if $found; 
   }
   break if $found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An regular expression to match the string `vserver foo2` is easy: `/vserver foo2/`.

Perhaps the easiest way to get multiple lines for this problem is to override the [`input record separator`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#%24INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) variable `$/` when you load this file, so that every record (everything between the "!"'s) is kept in a single scalar. For example,

```
local $/ = "!\n";
open my $fh, '<', $cisco_config_file;
my @configurations = <$fh>;
```

Now each element of `@configurations` contains an entire record. To get the matching records, now you just say

```
my @matching_records = grep { /vserver foo2/ } @configurations;
```

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response and great suggestions.